# How does an op-amp work without proper power supply?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, oscillator

I have built a chua's circuit following this diagram:
[image] 
Source: [Kennedy 92](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e385/fbd99486bc436f472c53ce12d1f69367c103.pdf)(pdf). The rectangle inside NR is and eight pin dual opamp.

Then, I remove the 9V battery **on the right**. It is replaced by a break. As a result, the negative power supply of the opamp (V- on diagram) is **not connected to anything else.**

I then use an oscilloscope to measure the voltage across C1. The scope shows an almost perfect sine wave.

**Question: how can a opamp supply power to the rest of the circuit if itself is not properly supplied by batteries? Why is it a sine wave?**

To be a sine wave, the components should be linear. **So what's the voltage-current characteristics of NR after removing the battery?**

PS: I use TL082 opamps.

Comment: wow, you found an ancient TL082? impressive.

Comment: also, around which voltage is your sine wave centered? and: didn't you just accidentally build an oscillator that is "pumped" by the remaining battery?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am sure that I have not connected the battery to anywhere else other than what's on the diagram. Why is TL082 ancient? Should I use a different one?

Comment: "why is it ancient": The datasheets you find for the Texas Instruments variant dates back to 1977, at least. It's simply ancient, and with that comes the need for supply voltages much larger than output voltages for proper function. Modern opamps are easier to use, have less noise, higher slew rate, lower power consumption, are better compensated...

Comment: With only half the supplies connected, you effectively reduced the full-swing opamp to something that can somewhat work with positively biased input resulting in positively biased output. But: you're operating the IC outside its specs, so to be honest, all speculation about what specifically happens is pretty much meaningless. If you're using a dual-supply opamp circuit with half the supply, it results in undefined behaviour.